# Missing time elapsed within a loop

Tags: r, performance, time

I noticed that the time elapsed within a loop doesn’t sum up to the total amount of time elapsed for the function. For instance

```
# run matrix multiplication 100 times
n = 5000
randommat = matrix(runif(n*n), nrow = n)
randomvec = runif(n)


RunSimu <- function(){
  timetot = c()
  for (i in 1:100){
    timetot[i] = system.time(randommat %*% randomvec)[3]
  }
  return(timetot)
}

# count the total time of running the function
system.time(timetot<- RunSimu()) # approx 7s

# sum up time elapsed for each loop
sum(timetot) # approx 1.5s
```

Intuitively, the totals amount of time elapsed for the function should be 100 * time elapsed for each iteration. But they seem to be quite different. Where is the missing time?

Comment: There better solutions for performance timing.  I suggest looking at the microbenchmark package

Comment: Any of `microbenchmark::microbenchmark(mul = randommat %*% randomvec)` or `bench::mark(mul = randommat %*% randomvec)` give a value comparable with `sum(timetot)`.

Comment: I simplified my function `RunSimu <- function(){
  for (i in 1:100){
    randommat %*% randomvec
  }
}`

It seems the program takes 1.6s to run. 

With that being said, save time elapsed to the vector for 100 times take 6s? Wow...unbelievable

Answer (score 1):

`system.time` by default calls `gc` every time, see `?system.time`. We can turn that off:

```
RunSimu2 <- function(){
  timetot = vector('numeric', 100)
  for (i in 1:100) {
    timetot[i] = system.time(randommat %*% randomvec, gcFirst = F)[3]
  }
  return(timetot)
}
system.time(timetot2<- RunSimu2()) # 2.69 
sum(timetot2) # 2.69
```

or with `proc.time`:

```
r3 <- function(){
  timetot = vector('numeric', 100)
  for (i in 1:100) {
    t1 <- proc.time()
    a = randommat %*% randomvec
    t2 <- proc.time()
    timetot[i] = (t2-t1)[3]
  }
  return(timetot)
}
system.time(t3 <- r3()) # 2.70 
sum(t3) # 2.7
```